# Graph Rendering error and Type Error in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, networkx

So, I got this code from [here](http://mark-kay.net/blog/2014/08/15/generating-a-network-graph-of-twitter-followers-using-python-and-networkx/) - program 3 on how to generate a network graph. I have tweaked it so that each node which is at a certain distance from a graph is rendered in a different color

```
import networkx as net
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict
import math
#%matplotlib inline

twitter_network = [ line.strip().split('\t') for line in file('twitter_network.csv') ]

o = net.DiGraph()
hfollowers = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for (twitter_user, followed_by, followers) in twitter_network:
    o.add_edge(twitter_user, followed_by, followers=int(followers))
    hfollowers[twitter_user] = int(followers)

SEED = 'NitinJamadagni'
#centre around the SEED node and set radius of graph
g = net.DiGraph(net.ego_graph(o, SEED, radius=4))

#modified trim functions
def trim_degrees_ted(g, degree=1):
    g2 = g.copy()
    d = net.degree(g2)
    for n in g2.nodes():
        if n == SEED: continue # don't prune the SEED node
            if d[n] <= degree:
            g2.remove_node(n)

    return g2

def trim_edges_ted(g, weight=1):
    g2 = net.DiGraph()
    for f, to, edata in g.edges_iter(data=True):
        if f == SEED or to == SEED: # keep edges that link to the SEED node
            g2.add_edge(f, to, edata)
        elif edata['followers'] <= weight:
            g2.add_edge(f, to, edata)
    return g2

print 'g: ', len(g)
core = trim_degrees_ted(g, degree=0)
print 'core after node pruning: ', len(core)
core = trim_edges_ted(core, weight=300)
print 'core after edge pruning: ', len(core)

nodeset_types = { 0:'nil',1:'nil',2:'nil' }
shit = net.shortest_path_length(o,SEED)
nodesets = defaultdict(list)

for tt,ty in nodeset_types.iteritems():
    nodesets[tt] = [ x[0] for x in shit.iteritems() if x[1]==int(tt) ]


pos = net.spring_layout(core) # compute layout

colours = ['yellow','red','green']

plt.figure(figsize=(18,18))
plt.axis('off')

i = 0

#different color for each node
for k in range[0,3]:
    net.draw_networkx_nodes(core, pos, nodelist=[x[0] for x in shit.iteritems() if x[1] == k], node_size=int(10/(k+1)), node_color=colours[k])


net.draw_networkx_edges(core, pos, width=0.5, alpha=0.5)

alphas = { 0: 1.0, 1: 0.5, 2: 0.5}
for k in nodesets.keys():
    for n in nodesets[k]:
        x, y = pos[n]
        plt.text(x, y+0.02, s=n, alpha=alphas[k], horizontalalignment='center', fontsize=9)

plt.savefig("path.png")
```

On running - 
    python filename.py

It gives me a graph with all nodes in yellow color and output on terminal

```
g:  142
core after node pruning:  142
core after edge pruning:  142
Not TED 142
TED 0
colourmap:  {'Not TED': 'yellow', 'TED': 'red'}
```

On running line by line in interpreter, I get error here -

```
  for k in range[0,3]:
...     net.draw_networkx_nodes(core, pos, nodelist=[x[0] for x in shit.iteritems() if x[1] == k], node_size=int(10/(k+1)), node_color=colours[k])
... 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

- What is the error ?
- Why do I get 'TED' and 'Not TED' even though I don't have it anywehere in my program ?
- Any why is there no colours in a circle for nodes when it is interpreted line by line ?

Comment: Can you confirm whether the error Padraic pointed out fixes things?

Comment: @Joel
It fixeed runtime error. But the nodes aren't being colored according to depth.

Answer (score 0):

Use parens not square brackets, `range` is a function:

```
for k in range(0,3): # <- correct 

for k in range[0,3]: # < wrong
```

Comment: Oops... I didn't see that. How do I handle the coloring problem - different colors based on depth ?